# Extra option for a configurable product

Tags: product, configurable-product, custom-options

we are using magento 1.8.ce

The most products in our store are configurable products with associated simple products.

Now we going to sell Beanies from a brand (in different sizes)
Eacht size is a simple product associated with the configurable product.

Besides the beanies we also have matching scarves (the are simple products, one-size)

What i would like to see is when the beanie is shown, the customer has directly the option to buy the matching scarf too ...

And preferably the other way to ... when a customer buys a scarf he has the option to buy a matching beanie (with size selector too ...)

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Adding one more option (drop-down) will make it required, as in configurable product all attributes you add are mandatory to select before adding to cart. So this will make scarf required option and I'm not sure if you want it (since in this case client must buy scarf). Besides, following this way, you will have to edit all your associated simple products adding this new option, as child items should have unique combination of attributes.

I guess the better way will be to add scarf as related product (so it will be shown at product page and added to cart additionally).